# Как выбрать тот же элемент незаметно?

Tags: android, listview

Как выбрать тот же элемент ListView, что уже выбран, чтобы при этом не менялся внешний вид списка?
Список периодически обновляется. Если у выбранного пункта в старом списке и в обновленном один и тот же идентификатор, то нужно выбрать тот же самый элемент, что был выбран.
Выполнение

```
mListView.setSelection(savedItem);
```

естественно, приводит к тому, что список движется и нужный элемент оказывается на самом верху. Нужно сделать:

```
mListView.setSelectionFromTop(savedItem, y);
```

Остается только вопрос: откуда мне взять `y`? Или, может быть, есть другой способ решения этой проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:
Заводим переменную `int top = 2;`, пишем слушатель для списка `mListView`:

```
OnItemSelectedListener selectedListener = new OnItemSelectedListener(){

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {}
        savedItem = position;       
        top = v.getTop();
        ...
        //Дальше нужный код
    }
};
```

В том месте, где нужно выбрать тот же элемент:

```
mListView.setSelectionFromTop(savedItem, top);
```

Двойку сначала присваиваю по следующей причине. Если изначально `top = 0` и `savedItem!=0` (или если используем: `mListView.setSelection(savedItem);`), то для того, чтобы перейти к предыдущему пункту нужно нажимать клавишу "Вверх" дважды, с двойкой такой проблемы нет.